# Qt-default version issue on migration from RPi4 to NVIDIA Jetson Nano

Tags: qt, embedded-linux, ubuntu-18.04, nvidia-jetson, nvidia-jetson-nano

Having an issue on migrating a Qt project from **RPi4** to **NVIDIA Jetson Nano**. We wanted to migrate our project to Jetson Nano to improve image processing performance.

The qt dependency of our project is **>= 5.11**. But Jetson Nano uses **Ubuntu 18.04.4** and it has qt5-default package pre-installed in it (in my understanding some system files use it). And this **qt5-default** packages version is **5.9.5**.

I tried to downgrade my qt dependency, but every change made lead to harder to fix issue.

I tried to upgrade default qt5 version but couldn't find any similar guidance. The guides/questions already exists are about x86 etc. environment. Couldn't find any ARM based solution. The qt downloads doesn't give any buildable for ARM env (or I can't find them). The official documents only talks about cross-compiling.

What should I do to overcome this issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can try to build a newer version from sources. However until now I wasn't able to successfully build it on the Nano. So no cross-compilation but instead directly compile it on the nano.

Comment: Where can I find sources of qt arm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I finally was able to successfully compile QT 5.12.9 on the Nano itself (no cross compilation).

The steps I did:

```
git clone https://code.qt.io/qt/qt5.git
cd qt5
git checkout 5.12.9
```

Then

```
git submodule update --init --recursive
cd ~
mkdir qt5-build
cd qt5-build
```

Configure and build

```
../qt5/configure -nomake examples -nomake tests -skip qtwebengine
make
sudo make install
```

Make took like nearly a whole day to compile all sources. Also I had some compilation errors before. However after skipping webengine and not building the tests and examples in ./configure I was finally able to sucessfully make it.

Comment: Thanks. I definitely used your suggestions in my situation. But even though a different qt5 version is installed, I couldn't used it bug free. I'm still working on it, and I will add if anything good comes up with my work.